# Objective c reassign variable

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 variables:

1. `UIView *view1;`
2. `UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init]`

When I assign `view1=view2` - should I release `view2`? Or just release `view1`?
Or `view1 = [view2 retain]; [view1 release];` is right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on what `view1` and `view2` are at the time of your `view1 = view2`. If it's like this:

```
UIView *view1;
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Then it's totally fine to just do:

```
view1 = view2;
```

If however `view1` already points to an object such as in this:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Then you would want to (probably) do this:

```
[view1 release];
view1 = [view2 retain];
```

I say probably because, well, it depends on what you are wanting to do. Maybe you don't want the `retain` on `view2` because you might not want to have a strong reference to it.

Of course all this is moot if you just use ARC anyway :-D.

Answer (score 0):

If you own an object (allocate, retain or copy it), you must release it. If you don't own it you don't release it.

That is to say, that view2 owns the view, and view1 doesn't.  You should release view2, but not view1.